# Domain of the function

Tags: calculus

Suppose $f(x)=\displaystyle \frac{x+1}{1+\frac{1}{x+1}}$. When $x=-1$, then $\displaystyle \frac{1}{x+1}$ is undefined. However if we multiply top and bottom by $x+1$, then $f(x)=\displaystyle \frac{(x+1)^2}{x+2}$.

Should the domain of $f$ be $\mathbb{R}-\{-2\}$ or you also need to consider $-1$ too so the domain would be $\mathbb{R}-\{-2,-1\}$?

Comment: The second option. You can't multiply top and bottom by $x+1$ when $x=-1$, since then, you're dividing by $0$.

Comment: consider, $\frac{1}{2}=\frac{0\times 1}{0\times 2}$?

Comment: @David Mitra. That is right but you can extend the domain to include -1 since the limit of f(x) for x tending to -1 exists and actually is 0.

Comment: @Urgje Also if the limit would not exist you can extend the domain. The only thing is then that the result is not continuous. Secondly the extended function is off course *another* function than the original one and you are not talking about the domain of the original one anymore.

Comment: To answer your question , simply think about this : $f(x)=1$ and $g(x) = \frac{x}{x}$ are not same . $g(0)$ doesn't exist , you can construct a similar argument for your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have written it, the domain of $f$ is the set of values we can put in and get a sensible output. therefore, the domain is $\mathbb{R}-\{-1,-2\}$. *However*, you can define a new function, 
$$
g(x) =
\begin{cases}
f(x), & \text{if }x \in \mathbb{R}, x \ne-1,-2\\
0, & \text{if }x=-1
\end{cases}
$$
Which, despite being piecewise, is still continuous and all of those nice things, and has the domain $\mathbb{R}-\{-2\}$

Answer (score 1):

What you write implies that $f$ is a function, although it does not say exactly which one. The conventional meaning of "function" requires that when it is specified, its domain is given *before* the behaviour of the function is defined (for instance by an expression describing the values of the function); many people will also insist that a codomain (set from which the values of the functions are taken) be specified, but not everyone agrees about this. Anyway, asking for the domain of a *function* is a bit silly, since it should be obvious from the definition; what is probably meant is the set of real values $x$ for which the *expression* $\frac{x+1}{1+\frac{1}{x+1}}$ is meaningful, and this set is $\Bbb R\setminus\{-1,-2\}$.

Since the question does not completely specify the function$~f$ (by not mentioning a domain), one cannot really answer the question. The domain could very well be the positive real numbers, or the complex numbers with real part${}>-1$, if one were inclined to define such a function; of course $\Bbb R\setminus\{-1,-2\}$ is also possible. With the given expression the domain cannot however include $-1$ or $-2$, although one could add one or more clauses to cater for those arguments, and then they would be in the domain.